# What are the managed/crawled properties which are related to the publishing startdate and publishing enddate?

Tags: search-results, managed-property, crawled-property

I created a new publishing site. When I create a new article page I can select the publishing startdate and the publishing enddate. I have a custom news webpart where I would like to show only the newsarticle which are between the publishing start and end date. I use search. Which managed and crawled property is related to these OOTB fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

internal field names are normaly `StartDate` and `_EndDate`...

Now you can go to your SSA -> Search Schema (left) -> Crawled Properties (top) -> Search for your field..

On the table you can find the column `Mapped Crawled Properties`, where you can see the managed property name

[image]